# using sed to replace some 64 based encoded strings (calling external echo + base64)

Tags: bash, sed, ldap, base64

I'm using `ldapsearch` to query AD servers. Some results are 64 encoded (always with `::` before), like:

```
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
company:: QWRQIFNlcnZpw6dvcw==
company: ROFF
```

Manually, I can decode those encoded strings with:

```
echo QWRQIFNlcnZpw6dvcw== | base64 -d
```

But I'm not able to convert all strings using `sed` (to replace only the encoded strings).

This works, but does do the replacement. It is used just for debug.

```
cat output.txt | sed "s/:: \(.\+\)/: `echo \\\1`/"
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
company: QWRQIFNlcnZpw6dvcw==
company: ROFF
```

What I would like to do is:

```
cat output.txt | sed "s/:: \(.\+\)/: `echo \\\1 | base64 -d`/"
base64: invalid input
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
company: 
company: ROFF
```

`base64` complains about the input, but it looks good to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think because `echo \\\1 | base64 -d` is executed in a subshell (interpreted by the shell, not by sed) so the value passed to base64 is the raw one (`\1`).

Comment: In the first case `echo \\\1` == "\1" and sed will replace it with the matching pattern (the base64-encoded string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `` sed "s/:: \(.\+\)/: `echo \\\1`/" `` and `` sed "s/:: \(.\+\)/: `echo \\\1 | base64 -d`/" `` the subshell `` `...` `` is expanded before `sed` even runs. Therefore `base64` complains that it cannot decode the literal string `\1`.

You have to instruct `sed` (which has a different syntax than bash) to call an external program. Standard `sed` cannot call external programs. See [How to embed a shell command into a sed expression?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48325/187122). But GNU `sed` can:

```
sed -E "s/(.*:): (.+)/printf %s '\1 '; echo '\2' | base64 -d/e"
```

This assumes that the line you are replacing does not contain any `'`. In your case, this shouldn't be a problem I think.

Answer (score 4):

With *GNU sed* you can use `s///e`:

```
$ cat file
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
company:: QWRQIFNlcnZpw6dvcw==
company: ROFF
$ cat file | gsed -E "s/(.*):: (.*)/printf %s '\\1: '; echo '\\2' | base64 -d/"
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
printf %s 'company: '; echo 'QWRQIFNlcnZpw6dvcw==' | base64 -d
company: ROFF
$ cat file | gsed -E "s/(.*):: (.*)/printf %s '\\1: '; echo '\\2' | base64 -d/e"
company: Medidata
company: Milestone
company: AdP Serviços
company: ROFF
```

---

The [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) for `s///e`:

> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. **If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output.** A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed extension.